# binding validation error using ElementName path

Tags: silverlight

TextBox1:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" Text="{Binding IdNumber, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" />
```

TextBox2:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox2" Text="{Binding Text,ElementName=TextBox1, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Currently: using above code Text binding is working fine but error validation is not working.
Expectation: If suppose, any validation error happens in TextBox1 should reflect in TextBox2.

Answer (score 0):

Validation states are triggered based upon the property, not the value. In the case of TextBox2, it is irrelevant that there is an error in your IdNumber property as the Text property of TextBox1 does not have any errors.

The only way you can display the error for IdNumber in TextBox2 is to bind to the IdNumber property.
Binding to the IdNumber property will also cause TextBox1 and TextBox2 to display the same text